# Decrease the images size in KB

Tags: image

Like I said, picture quality is more important than the size but i have to balance. Want to make the picture file size too small.
but would rather like to see better lighting effect and good quality image.

for main-light background, since most of the area will be covered by our main-content white background, so we can delete those area to make the file smaller at same time to keep the good quality.But that is not working.

help me.
[image]

Comment: Go here... http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear. What is the context? Where is the image coming from? On what type of input the are of image will be selected? And most important [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Archer this is not working in all browser.

Comment: It works in the vast majority of them and is an online solution to your issue.  What you really need is a graphics package as you can't do what you're asking with client-side code.

Comment: You could consider making an SVG background but it wouldn't work in all browsers. Here's a [compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css)

Comment: @Archer i have to use the form this but IE browser looks different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use a image editor software and save the file as a web device.

Also the other option is to save the lighting effect as a `.png` file and set the blue background in CSS.

Say your lighting image is being called: `lighting-effect.png`

then use css of

```
div{
   background: url('lighting-effect.png') no-repeat top center #1369AE;
}
```

This will save image size because the image will not have to hold the blue color in it.

Comment: it will still bring down the size and not mean you have to keep editing the image just to change the background color is you wish to in future.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for **Decrease the images size in KB**, its not possible to do that in client side (using css, html, javascript, jquery). You may try server side scriptings such as ASP, PHP etc.

But for your question, you may try some software like Adobe Photoshop to reduce image size or you may try something like **[JPG/JPEG Image File Size Reducer and Batch Image Resizer](http://download.cnet.com/JPG-JPEG-Image-File-Size-Reducer-and-Batch-Image-Resizer/3000-10247_4-10905130.html)**

Answer (score 0):

http://www.evisiontesting.com/ryanh/TEST/images/aa.jpg

500kb to 50kb.. without hurting quality this is as good as you can get with it... unless you render it using CSS or something.

Use Photoshop, Save For Web & Devices, pick an option that works with quality/good size and that's how you properly handle images for web :)